# Compiling OpenGL and GLUT OSX

Tags: c, macos, opengl

I am having difficulty compiling a C program using the OpenGL and GLUT frameworks on Mac OSX. I am just getting started and I attempted to run code from this tutorial, on how to install OpenGL. http://www.prinmath.com/csci5229/misc/install.html.

Here is the code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile it with:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL
```

I am receiving this error:

```
foo.c:2:23: error: GLUT/glut.h: No such file or directory
```

After doing some further research here, http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/, I looked in /System/Library/Frameworks/ and both OpenGL.framework, and GLUT.framework where present.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Works for me under 10.9 DP5 and Clang LLVM 5.0.

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me without installing anything else. The only different thing I had was `-L/System/Library/Frameworks`, so the whole compiling line should be `gcc -o foo foo.c -L/System/Library/Frameworks -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install OpenGL Utility Toolkit `glutg3-dev` lib.If it is already there then compile with `-lglut -lGLU -lGL` option.

Answer (score 4):

Without installing glutg3-dev you can use OS X GLUT and OpenGL frameworks as follows

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -L/System/Library/Frameworks -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL
```

notice that it is important to tell the compiler the path to the frameworks

Comment: You shouldn't normally need the `-L` option, the compiler knows where to find the frameworks. They are not in `/System/Library/Frameworks` anymore if you use a recent version of Xcode. Well, the frameworks used at runtime are still there. But not the development part of the frameworks, like the header files.

Answer (score 3):

On Catalina (10.15.7), XCode 12.4 (12D4e) here's what worked for me :

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
...
```

Then compile with

```
gcc code.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL
```